# Connection with Cassandra and Database error

Tags: python, database, command-line, cassandra

I have installed Cassandra and have set path for python as well. When I try to start cqlsh from the command line with below command:

```
python cqlsh localhost 9160
```

I am getting error as,

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax File "cqlsh". line 20 python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(not (0x020700b0 < sys.hexversion < 0x03000000))' 2>/dev/null \

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Cqlsh is an executable by itself and doesn't need to by invoked via python executable.

So just enter cqlsh instead, it will by default connect to localhost.

```
Cqlsh
```

In case there is authorization enabled and Cassandra is listening on a specific IP address other than localhost, you can then invoke cqlsh using

```
Cqlsh -h ipaddress -u username -p password
```